# Suppress large output to R console

Tags: r, console, output

How can I make R check whether an object is too large to print in the console? "Too large" here means larger than a user-defined value.

Example: You have a list `f_data` with two elements `f_data$data` (a 100MB data.frame) and `f_data$info` (for instance, a vector). Assume you want to inspect the first few entries of the `f_data$data` data.frame but you make a mistake and type `head(f_data)` instead of `head(f_data$data)`. R will try to print the whole content of `f_data` to the console (which would take forever).
Is there somewhere an option that I can set in order to suppress the output of objects that are larger than let's say 1MB?

Edit: Thank you guys for your help. After implementing the `max.rows` option I realized that this gives indeed the desired output. BUT the problem that the output takes very long to show up still persists. I will give you a proper example below.

```
df_nrow=100000
df_ncol=100
#create list with first element being a large data.frame
#second element is a short vector
test_list=list(df=data.frame(matrix(rnorm(df_nrow*df_ncol),nrow=df_nrow,ncol=df_ncol)),
               vec=1:110)

#only print the first 100 elements of an object
options(max.print=100)

#head correctly displays the first row of the data.frame
#BUT for some reason the output takes really long to show up in the console (~30sec)
head(test_list)
#let's try to see how long exactly
system.time(head(test_list))
#   user  system elapsed 
#      0       0       0
#well, obviously system.time is not the proper tool to measure this

#the same problem if I just print the object to the console without using head
test_list$df
```

I assume that R performs some sort of analysis on the object being printed and this is what takes so long.

Edit 2:
As per my comment below, I checked whether the problem persists if I use a `matrix` instead of a `data.frame`.

```
#create list with first element being a large MATRIX
test_list=list(mat=matrix(rnorm(df_nrow*df_ncol),nrow=df_nrow,ncol=df_ncol),vec=1:110)

#no problem
head(test_list)

#no problem
test_list$mat
```

Could it be that the output to the console is not really efficiently implemented for `data.frame` objects?

Comment: I usually set `options(max.print)` to prevent overflow of the console. This limits printing the number of characters, not size, though.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I believe it actually limits printing of 'elements', which will be approximately rows for a data.frame and entries for a list.

Comment: Ah, mea culpa. That's what I meant, elements. Thanks for the correction. I just checked, and an element would be a number in a data.frame. I have a data.frame with 40 variables and limit printing to 500. It displays only 12 rows (12 * 40 = 480).

Comment: I see now that this problem does not show up if I replace the `data.frame` by a `matrix`. Maybe it has something to do with how `data.frame`s are stored. As far as I know they are a list of vectors, each vector being one column of the `data.frame`. Since `max.print` applies to rows, R can not simply iterate through the elements of the `data.frame`...

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no such option, but you can check the size of an object with `object.size` and print it if is lower than a threshold (measure in bytes), for example:

```
print.small.objects <- function(x, threshold = 1e06, ...)
{
  if (object.size(x) < threshold) {
    print(x, ...)
  } else {
    cat(paste("too big object\n"))
    print(object.size(x))
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That would work. However, often I just print the object to the console without using `head` or `print` or any other function. And if it happens that I forget that it is a very large object that I am trying to print to the console, the problem described in the edit of my question persists.

Comment: `showDefault` may be the function that you would like to modify. I think that's the function that prints an object when you just type its name and press the return key. You may have a look at the function `showDefault` in the methods package (or type `showDefault` at the R prompt). Alternatively you could define an `S3` class to store your `matrix` or `data.frame` objects and create a `show` method for that class.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that you could adjust up to 100MB.  It basically only prints the first 6 rows and 5 columns if the object's size is above 8e5 bytes.  You could also turn this into a function and place it in your `.Rprofile`

```
> lst <- list(data.frame(replicate(100, rnorm(1000))), 1:10)
> sapply(lst, object.size)
# [1] 810968     88
> lapply(lst, function(x){
      if(object.size(x) > 8e5) head(x)[1:5] else x
  })
#[[1]]
#          X1         X2          X3          X4         X5
#1  0.3398235 -1.7290077 -0.35367971  0.09874918 -0.8562069
#2  0.2318548 -0.3415523 -0.38346083 -0.08333569 -1.1091982
#3  0.0714407 -1.4561768  0.50131914 -0.54899188  0.1652095
#4 -0.5170228  1.7343073 -0.05602883  0.87855313  0.4025590
#5  0.6962212 -0.3179930  0.28016057  1.05414456 -0.5172885
#6  0.9471200  1.4424843 -1.46323827 -0.78004192 -1.3611820
#
#[[2]]
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```